# is any smooth function a difference of plurisubharmonic functions?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f: \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^\infty$ function, is it true that $f = f_1 - f_2$ where $f_1, f_2$ are plurisubharmonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. The only reference I know is the short paper: 
*Representation of an infinitely differentiable function by a difference of plurisubharmonic functions*
by A. B. Sekerin, Mathematical Notes, 1986, 40:5, 841–846.
It is available at

http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=mzm&paperid=5215&option_lang=eng

in Russian, with links to the English translation.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1157412)

Comment: Well it is a reference rather than a link. You can delete if you want but I think it may be useful. I can't write the essential parts of the argument right now (especially since the reference does more than what is asked) though it would be better for sure.